# Why won't my LinkedList work?

Tags: java, linked-list

I've searched all of over SO but I haven't quite found exactly what I'm looking for because it's overly complicated.  I want to know why I'm getting this error (posted below).  My code seems logically correct but for reason I'm getting the null pointer exception.

Here's my `HashTable.java` file:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HashTable {
    public static void lastFourDigitsStudent(Student s) {
        LinkedList<Student>[] llStudent = new LinkedList[1000];

        String a = s.getId().substring(4,8);
        int lastFourDigits = Integer.parseInt(a);
        int hashFunction = lastFourDigits % 1000;

        llStudent[hashFunction].add(s);
    }
}
```

Here's the `error` I'm getting:

```
Type safety: The expression of type LinkedList[] 
needs unchecked conversion to conform to LinkedList<Student>[]
```

Comment: Where are you getting a NullPointer? What is `s`? How are you calling this method?

Comment: @cricket_007 then it won't compile. You can't create a array of parametised types. This does compile, but with a warning

Comment: @ChandlerBing According to the user it's an error, so I suppose it's not compiling.

Comment: You created an array of 1000 `LinkedList` but you never initialise them

Comment: @litelite didn't read that. Just saw the warning message. Sorry to bother.

Comment: @ChandlerBing not stress, happen to me all the time ;)

Comment: @cricket_007 In my main, I'm calling it like so: `lastFourDigitsStudent(student1);` where `student1` is a `Student` object.

Comment: @bojack Please distinguish a compile-time warning from a run-time error, i.e., (in your case:) NullPointerException.

Comment: @laune Why on earth would you flag this question?  I'm sorry if I'm not an expert in Java like you.  I clearly said I searched SO for this exact problem but didn't find what I was looking for because of it being so arcane.  You don't need to flex your ego like this.

Comment: @bojack First, I did not "flag" your question. I marked it as duplicate, for the stated reason - this and litelite's comment should be enough to help you find the problem. And I pointed out to you that, while your title and text indicate a NPE, you quote a compile-time warning which isn't very meaningful. - If all this help hurts your tender hide you should try and write better questions. -- Marking a question as duplicate is standard practice.

Comment: @laune Yeah, "tender inside".  I didn't intentionally try to make a post that's not meaningful.  I'm new to Java. I didn't distinguish compile-time warning from a run-time error correctly by accident & I'm sure as hell you understood what I meant and as a result you shot down the post which just shows you're just trying to flex your muscle.  You're forgetting you were once new at this as well.  Eat glass.

Comment: @bojack What in "Marking a question as duplicate is standard practice" do you not understand? You are talking nonsense when you say "shot down the post". -- Of course it was clear to me that you didn't quite know why you got the NPE, but I'm sure you know that by now.